# Zend Cron job raises segmentation fault

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron, segmentation-fault

I have a script in Zend framework 1.11.11 that runs with as a cron job which was working great for about 10 days and then stopped. The script is takes XML and inserts the contents into a database table.

When I run the script with SSH:

- If the database table has about 610 items stored the script is terminated and returns segmentation fault in terminal.
- If I delete the table contents from phpMyAdmin, the script inserts ~300-400 items and stops returning terminated in terminal.
- If I run the script again it insert items until database table is reaching the ~610 items and returns segmentation fault in terminal.
- If I run it again is not inserting any other item and returns with segmentation fault error.

I have the deluxe plan with GoDaddy hosting.

The script code I run is this:

```
<?php    
    require_once 'init.php';   
    $started = Zend_Date::now();
    $log = 'started: '.$started->toString('dd/MM/YYYY H:m:s').PHP_EOL;
    $xmlOptions = $options['xml'];
    $mapper = new Application_Model_Mapper();       
    $striper = new Zend_Filter_StripTags();
    $count = 0; 

    try {
        $client = new Zend_Http_Client($xmlOptions['url']);
        $client->setConfig(array('timeout' => 60));
        $request = $client->request();

        if ($request->getStatus() != 404) {
            file_put_contents('downloaded.xml', $request->getBody());
            $items = simplexml_load_file('downloaded.xml',
                'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);   

            foreach ($items as $xml) {               
                if (!$mapper->exist($xml->{$xmlOptions['id']},
                    $xml->{$xmlOptions['store']})) {
                    $endDate = new Zend_Date($xml->{$xmlOptions['until']});
                    $diff = Zend_Date::now()->compare($endDate);

                    if ($diff == -1) {
                        $item =new Application_Model_Item();
                        $url = $xml->{$xmlOptions['image']};
                        $url_length = strlen($url);
                        $image_url = 'images/items/'.$xml->
                            {$xmlOptions['id']}.'_'.$xml->
                            {$xmlOptions['store']}. substr($xml->
                            $xmlOptions['image']},$url_length-4,4);

                        if (file_get_contents($url))
                            file_put_contents('../'.$xmlOptions['public'].'/'.
                                $image_url, file_get_contents($url));
                        $item->xml_id = $xml->{$xmlOptions['id']};
                        $item->title = $xml->{$xmlOptions['title']};
                        $item->description = $striper->filter($xml->
                            {$xmlOptions['description']});
                        $item->link = $xml->{$xmlOptions['link']};
                        $item->image = $image_url;
                        $mapper->addItem($item);                        
                        $count++;
                   }
                }
            }
        }
        $log .= "added: $count items".PHP_EOL;          
        $log .= 'removed: '.$mapper->removeExpiredItems().' items'.PHP_EOL;     
    }

    catch (Exception $ex) {
        $log .= PHP_EOL.'ERROR: '.$ex->getLine().':'.$ex->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
    }

    $end = Zend_Date::now();
    $log .= 'ended: '.$end->toString('dd/MM/YYYY H:m:s').PHP_EOL;
    $elapsed = $end->sub($started);
    $log .= 'elapsed: '.$elapsed->toString('m:s').PHP_EOL;
    $log .= 'Errors'.PHP_EOL.$errors;
    echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.$log;
    $h = Zend_Date::now()->toString('dd_MM H_m_s');
    file_put_contents('logs/xml '.$h.'.log', $log);
?>
```

And the init.php:

```
<?php
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    set_time_limit(600);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '96M');

    //log errors
    set_error_handler('err_handle',E_ALL);
    $errors = '';

    function err_handle($code,$string,$file,$line,$context) {
        $errors .= $string.PHP_EOL;
    }

    defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
        || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

    // Define application environment
    defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
        || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 
        'development'));

    set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
        realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
        get_include_path(),
    )));

    /** Zend_Application */
    require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

    $application = new Zend_Application(
        APPLICATION_ENV,
        APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
    $options = $application->getOptions();
    $application->bootstrap();  
?>
```

Comment: `$errors .= $string.PHP_EOL;` won't work. You need to add `global $errors;` before it. Perhaps you run out of memory? Where does the segfault occur?

Comment: Thanks for the global, segmentation fault occurs while it inserts new items. When the items in database are ~610items it throws the error right after the XML downloading. My hosting plan has 1gb size limit. I think the problem is in database.